# Magnetic core memory construction, and proper cores to use

Tags: memory, core

I'm looking to experiment with magnetic core memory. I want to make a small magnetic memory module for use with a micro controller.

There is [a post](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/42568/magnetic-core-transfer-loops-logic) on stack exchange itself that gave lots of relevant info, but most of it seemed to be using old stock of magnetic cores built for the task of magnetic core memory.

Most of the old stock for the magnetic cores seems to be quite expensive, I'm just looking to experiment with a small quantity. (I don't need, say, a container of 45,000 cores) Is there any such ferrite ring manufactured right now that would be suited for this?

I was looking at [these cores](http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en?pv77=4608&FV=fff40034%2Cfff802aa&k=ferrite%20core&mnonly=0&newproducts=0&ColumnSort=0&page=1&quantity=0&ptm=0&fid=0&pageSize=25) on Digikey, would they be appropriate for the task?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but probably still useful for you: https://sites.google.com/site/wayneholder/one-bit-ferrite-core-memory

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure that the ferrite can be permanently magnetized. This is sometimes referred to as "hard" ferrite — one that has a nearly-square B-H curve.

Most of the modern ferrites used in EMC work are "soft" ferrites, designed mainly for their loss characteristics, and they do not retain any significant magnetization.